# Contraction.fix resulted an error "IndexError: string index out of range"

Tags: python, nlp

I was applying contractions.fix to a text but it resulted in a error 'IndexError: string index out of range' after applying try catch block to text I managed to find out that it is throwing error in two specific words.

```
%%time
import re
import contractions
import unicodedata
​
text = our_text
​
expanded_words = []    
for word in text.split():
    try:
        expanded_words.append(contractions.fix(word))   
    except:
        print(word,len(word))
```

Output :

İtburnu 7

İletişim 8

```
contractions.fix('İtburnu')
```

output : "IndexError: string index out of range"

Why these two specific words are causing the error??

Comment: My guess is that the `contractions` module isn't get up to handle Turkish characters.

Comment: I am not sure as contractions can handle some Turkish words directly for Ex -                  print(contractions.fix('Aşk'),contractions.fix('Köpek'))     Output :  Aşk Köpek

Comment: Also in my case there are 63042228 total words in our_text and I am getting error on only these two specific words.

Answer (score 0):

This is a UTF-8 character issue.

If you try

> contractions.fix('Itburnu')

and

> contractions.fix('Iletisim')

you will get output.